# Bluetooth headset not working

Tags: bluetooth-speaker

I am using ubuntu 15.10. My Bluetooth headset is recognized but I cannot select it in the sound options. How can I try to fix it or get correct driver?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After successful connecting of the bluetooth headset, try
`sudo -i pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`

If that then allows you to select the headset as an output device, you can make the following changes:

```
nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Comment out the following lines:

```
#.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
#load-module module-bluetooth-discover
#.endif
```

Then in:

```
nano /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11
```

Find the following lines and add after them:

```
if [ x”$SESSION_MANAGER” != x ] ; then
/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-xsmp “display=$DISPLAY session_manager=$SESSION_MANAGER” > /dev/null
fi

# Add the following lines:
/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
# /usr/bin/pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect #<-- Uncomment to automatically select headset on connection
```